# How can I get the variable from other function to another component on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

Is that possible to use a variable of different function in another component ? I seperated function part and component part that is like :

[image: design structure]

and my function:

```
export function createCombos(number_of_cells) {
  number_of_cells = parseInt(number_of_cells);
  const real_number = Math.sqrt(number_of_cells);
  const arr = Array(real_number)
    .fill(0)
    .map((x) => Array(real_number).fill(0));
}
```

I want to use "arr" which I declared in "createCombos" function.

The component that I wanted to use in :
[image: Board.js]

I want to use like that :

```
import { createCombos } from "../functions/Combo";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function Board() {
  var [arra, setArra] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    createCombos(prompt("enter a number:"));
     **setArra(createCombos.arr);**
  });
  return <div>
     **arra.map((a)=> { 
        <p> {a} </p> 
         })**
    </div>;
}
```

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Unless I'm missign something, you can `return arr;` from `createCombos` and then access it when you call it: `const arr =  createCombos(prompt(...));`. You can set your state to `arr`. Also make sure you `return` your JSX from your arrow function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Combo.js, return the array from createCombos function.

```
export function createCombos(number_of_cells) {
  number_of_cells = parseInt(number_of_cells);
  const real_number = Math.sqrt(number_of_cells);
  const arr = Array(real_number)
    .fill(0)
    .map((x) => Array(real_number).fill(0));
  return arr
}
```

change the React component to this.

```
import { createCombos } from "../functions/Combo";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function Board() {
  var [arra, setArra] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
   // save returned array to arr variable
    const arr = createCombos(prompt("enter a number:"));
    setArra(arr);
  });
  return <div>
     arra.map((a)=> { 
        <p> {a} </p> 
         })
    </div>;
}
```